# Should I prefix with this.myPrivateMethod if the name is same as public method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the module pattern like:

```
BLAH = ( function() {

  var someMethod = function(data) {

  };



  return {
      someMethod: function(data) {
          this.someMethod(data);
      }

  }

})();
```

Inside the public someMothod, is it good practise to reference the inner function using `this`?

Does it matter or it's just makes things clearer?

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to reference the "public" `someMethod`.

Comment: If this was me I'd name the private method `_someMethod`, remove confusion and since the method is private no one besides you will see the "ugly" nbame.

Comment: I think the yui standard is to do both, this._someMethod right?

Comment: Using *this* to reference the object *someMethod* has been assigned to isn't a good idea as a function's *this* value is set by the call, so if the function isn't called as `BLAH.someMethod()`, it probably won't reference the object assigned to `BLAH`.

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not work as expected. When `BLAH.someMethod()` is called,

```
someMethod: function(data) {
    this.someMethod(data);
}
```

it will keep calling the public `someMethod` recursively until there's a stack overflow.

To access the private function, you should not prefix it with `this.`. The private function is not a property of the current object. It is only available in the execution context of `someMethod`.

Comment: now I'm confused, so how do I reference the method when there is a name collision?

Comment: which method do you want to reference - the private or the public one?

Comment: I want to reference the private one.  I thought this.someMethod was going to reference the var someMethod = function(..) definition in the Blah object.

Comment: @Blankman - you example is referencing the public method. Here's how you would access the private method. `return { someMethod: function() { someMethod(data); } }`

Answer (score 2):

For more clarity, the above code could be written:

```
var Blah = (function(){

    Blah = function() {
    };

    Blah.prototype.someMethod = function( data ){
        ...
    }

    return Blah;
)();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a convention to make your code more readable (which shouldn't be undervalued). Doesn't make a difference from a functionality standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm not sure what you gain from having the *private* inner method.

This is the template I use for my projects, it's based on how jQuery does theirs.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    var MyObject = (function () {
        var myObj = {},
            _myInternalVariable = 'YAY';

        //Internal method
        function _internalMethod(){
        };

        //external variables
        myObj.debug = false;

        //version number
        myObj.version = "1.0";

        // Logs the message to the console, if it (the console) exists
        myObj.log = function (msg) {
            if (window.console && typeof console.log !== "undefined" && myObj.debug) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        };

        return myObj;
    })();

    window.MyObject = window.MO = MyObject ;
})(jQuery);
```